# What does this not work for getchar() method?

Tags: c, getchar

This was my own experiment to understand what goes under the hood, what does this program mean to the compiler?

```
main()
{
  int c;
  printf("%d\n",c);
  printf("%d ", getchar());


  while ((c == getchar()) != EOF){
    putchar(c);
  }
}
```

When I say c must equal getchar() (c == getchar()), does it not proceed through the while loop? Now I am really confused of my own code, of what c must mean!

Also, in this code:

```
main()
{
int c;
c = getchar()
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
putchar(c);
}
```

if we modify the `int c` to `int c = getchar()`, why cannot we somply write like this:

```
while (c != EOF)(
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
    }
```

The compiler should know from the previous statement that `c = getchar()`, why have to write the statement again? Sorry, if I am confused.

Comment: Perhaps try `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` ? And your first `printf()` is **undefined behavior**. You're evaluating a variable (`c`) that is at-that-point indeterminate.

Comment: while((c = getchar()) != EOF)

Comment: @DGomez  I wish to know what c==getchar() means! I have understood c = getchar()

Comment: @WhozCraig  wish to know what c==getchar() means! I have understood c = getchar()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ((c==getchar()) != EOF) {
  ...
}
```

is a while loop. It evaluates the condition for each iteration of the loop and terminates only if the condition is false.

In your case, the condition is:

```
(c==getchar()) != EOF)
```

which is a nonsensical expression, but let's examine it anyway:

First, the program will evaluate:

```
    getchar()
```

This grabs a keystroke from standard input. The value of the expression is the value of the key.

Then:

```
 c==getchar()
```

This takes the result of `getchar()` and compares it to whatever is currently in `c`. In your first program, `c` is uninitialized, so its value is indeterminate. If `c` had a defined value, then `c==getchar()` would evaluate to either `true` or `false`. Since `c` had no defined value, `c==getchar()` also has no defined value.

Now the program evaluates:

```
(c==getchar())
```

Which would still be `true` or `false`, except that in your case it is undefined.

The program next considers:

```
(c==getchar()) != EOF
```

That is, it compares the `true`-`false` value to `EOF`; this makes no particular sense, and in your case we still have the undefined behavior of an uninitialized `c`.

In sum, if `c` were initialized, the expression would fetch a key from standard input and then compare either `true` or `false` to `EOF`. As I said, it is a nonsensical expression.

Comment: +1 This code has been edited enough times now that my original comments in another answer probably make little sense. Imagine a mashination of *both* code samples together. The indeterminate `c` in the first printf, a `c` = getchar()` after, and `while((c == getchar()) != EOF)` after that. Hate when that happens. Nice breakdown, sir. (I could have been hallucinating. Had a lot of cough syrup tonight =P)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer Sir! Kindly appreciated!

Comment: Also, the question "The compiler should know..." - computers are like this at the core; they need to be told every little thing.  It's a curse and a blessing.  There may be a reason to want to enter that loop without first calling getchar().

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra equal sign that you need to remove:

```
while ((c == getchar()) != EOF){
```

should be

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
```

Here is what is happening. When `(c == getchar())` is executed, to begin with `c` is uninitialized, so it has some garbage value. That garbage value is compared to the next character in the input stream, to see if they are the same. The result of the comparison is going to be `0` (if they are different) or `1` (if they are same). The latter is very unlikely, but it is theoretically possible that by some lucky (?) chance, the garbage value does happen to match the next character in the input stream.

That `0` or `1` is then compared to see whether it matches `EOF`. Well, `EOF` is going to be some negative value; that's what it is by definition. Obviously `0` or `1` will never match any negative value, so your loop will be infinite.

As for your second code fragment:

```
c = getchar();
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

You're not checking whether the first character is `EOF`, as the value of `c` after the first `getchar()` will be immediately replaced by the assignment in the `while` condition. Assuming that there is a non-`EOF` first character, your code will work.

As for your third code fragment:

```
c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {     // corrected your typo of ( instead of {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
}
```

The reason why you have to write `c = getchar()` again inside your `while` loop is to update the value of `c` with the second and subsequent characters in the input stream. Otherwise, it will always compare the current value of `c`, which is the first character in the input stream, to `EOF`, and this too will be an infinite loop unless the first character does happen to be `EOF`.

The most concise way of accomplishing what you want is:

int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar (c);

... just like your second code fragment, minus the extra line that does the first `getchar()` and assigns it to `c`.

Comment: I understood that, i just wish to know hat c == getchar() means.

Comment: @user2282137 Think about what it means. It means you were comparing the *first* character you entered one line earlier against any character you enter after, and comparing the boolean result (0 or 1) against `EOF` (which is usually defined as (-1). Since `0` will never be `-1`, and `1` will never be `-1`, thus an infinite loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig For instance when I run the program and say type this:
a (the value of c will be?)
b (the value of c will be?)

When will c == getchar? Sorry, I am new.

Comment: @user2282137 What was `c` when you assigned it on the line above? Suppose it was 'a'. When do you suppose `c == getchar()` will be *true*? What will it be *in every other case*?

Comment: I modified my code like this to really understand what's going on:

while ((c == getchar()) != EOF){
    printf("%d\n", (c == getchar()));
    
    putchar(c);
  }

Comment: @user2282137 I know. See Rob's answer for a breakdown.

Comment: Thank you very very very much! I am glad for you guys to have been answering this, made my day!

Answer (score 2):

You're saying you want to look under the hood? Great! Let's dive in :)

`while ((c == getchar()) != EOF)`

As others have noted, this should be `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`. The reason you do assignment (`=`) rather than equality testing (`==`) is because you're actually rolling two lines of code into one: `c = getchar();` and `while(c != EOF)`. So if the current character being read is `k`, the program evaluates it in a way kind of like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
while ((c = 'k') != EOF)
while (('k') != EOF)
while ('k' != EOF)
while (1) // true
```

And it has the convenient side effect that `c` still has `k` inside for whatever you're planning on doing.

The other problem is here:

```
int c;
printf("%d\n",c);
```

`printf` will complain because you don't have anything assigned to `c` yet. It's been "declared", but not "initialized." It can't print something that's not there - and if it can, it would surely print something you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is great, kindly appreciated Sir!

Answer (score 0):

`c == getchar() != EOF` means

c == getchar() is true if `c` and the `result returned from getchar()` are the same.

`c == getchar()` will always be not equal to EOF (since neither true not false equals EOF) so the program should infinite loop printing the character that randomly showed up here since you never initialized c `int c;`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, its a great one, thank you!